# How to check function definition in FSI (F# Interactive)?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

In `Clojure`, I can use

```lisp
(doc my-function)     ; to check function documentation, and
(source my-function)  ; to check the function definition.
```

Is there any similar method in F# Interactive?

Comment: Not within FSI, but documentation exists, so in theory such a function could be written.